# Why Session is not working on server, is there any server side setting for it?

Tags: session, server, php

Why Session is not working on the server, is there any server-side setting for session variables.

[image]

As per above screenshot, firstly I am executing abc.php and then abcd.php.
when abc.php is executing it returns me the `Array ( [admin] => 1 )` and I am executing again abcd.php it returns me only blank array `Array ( )`.

its working perfect on localhost but not on the server, So is there any server-side setting is need to do for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the headers, make sure the server sets a cookie, and that a client sends it the next request.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for replying, do you want me to set the cookie?

Comment: No, `session_start` should set a cookie for you.

Comment: Google for how to do it in your browser. If it's a google chrome check the `Network` and `Application` tabs in the dev tools.

Comment: Please give us the details about the server environment. Sometimes php session directory may not have permission to write session file. you can check it by `php -i | grep session.save_path` on a linux server

Answer (score 1):

please check phpinfo() on the server and check the `session.save_path`.

and make sure this path and folder is available with writable permission.

[image]

In my case - there was no `'tmp'` folder. I have created and issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Check whether it is a session path issue.
You can follow the following instructions to set a new session path.

> By default, PHP stores session data in files and files are stored in
>   the /tmp directory of your server.Each session is stored in its own
>   file. echo session_save_path();
>
> session_save_path function returns the current session save path.If
>   session_save_path() function returns null,then session.save_path is
>   commented in your php.ini file.
>
> You can uncomment session.save_path session.save_path =
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Temp"
>
> To change the default path of stored session, you can use same
>   function session_save_path( ) but with the parameter which is the path
>   of the new directory
>
> session_save_path("/var/www/html/project/sess_save/");

And In case if you are working on frameworks like CodeIgniter. It is always better you define the session path in config.php